# Html hide button is hiding all buttons instead of one

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, hide

I am trying to hide a button when clicked.

component.ts:

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit, ChangeDetectionStrategy, ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';
import { DataService } from '../../shared/service/data.service';
import { TreeNode } from '../../shared/dto/TreeNode';

import html from './rightside.component.html';
import css from './rightside.component.css';

@Component({
  selector: 'rightside-component',
  template: html,
  providers: [DataService],
  styles: [css],
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})

export class RightSideComponent implements OnInit {
  selections: string[];
  @Input() treeNode: TreeNode<string>[];
  hide: boolean = false;

  constructor(private cd: ChangeDetectorRef) {}

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  getSelections() : TreeNode<string>[] {
    if (typeof(this.treeNode) == "undefined" || (this.treeNode) === null) {
      return [];
    }
    return this.treeNode;
  }

  deselect(item: TreeNode<string>): void {
    this.hide = true;
    if((item.children) !== null) {
      item.children.forEach(element => {
        this.deselect(element);
      });
    }
    item.selected = false;
  }

}
```

component.html:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<div>
  <ul class="selection-list">
    <li *ngFor="let item of getSelections()">
      <button class="btn" (click)="deselect(item)" *ngIf="!hide">
        <i class="fa fa-close"> {{ item.displayName }} </i>
      </button> 
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

When I click on any button, all of the items are disappearing. I want just the clicked item to disappear. When I select the checkbox again, the item should re-appear. I want to implement something similar to this plunkr I found but for my data structure :

http://next.plnkr.co/edit/1Fr83XHkY0bWd9IzOwuT?p=preview&utm_source=legacy&utm_medium=worker&utm_campaign=next&preview

How can I fix this? Let me know if any other code is required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using the common `hide` variable, use `selected` attribute in each item since you are making it false when you deselect.

```
<button class="btn" (click)="deselect(item)" *ngIf="item.selected">
   <i class="fa fa-close"> {{ item.displayName }} </i>
</button>
```

Comment: This is not making any of the items appear when selected.

Comment: @TeeJay forgot remove the ! mark. Thanks for pointing it out. :)

Comment: It worked. When I click for the first time on a button, it hides it. However, when I click on any other buttons after that, I have to click multiple times on it (or on the screen and then click on that button again) for it to get hidden. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: It actually contains many components and has dependencies so a plunkr seems difficult. I have asked a question and posted the code here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51794978/html-button-works-with-single-click-only-for-the-first-time-angular

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
  hide= [];

    <div>
      <ul class="selection-list">
        <li *ngFor="let item of getSelections();let i=index">
          <button class="btn" (click)="deselect(item: 
           TreeNode<string>);hide[i]=!hide[i]" *ngIf="hide[i]">
            <i class="fa fa-close"> {{ item.displayName }} </i>
          </button> 
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
```

Comment: Where would I call the deselect function then? I have updated my question and added code about the TreeNode datastructure.

Answer (score 0):

All your items disappears because they all share the same "hide" attribute so when you click on One of them it will change for all the items. What you should have is an attribute for each item (this attribute should be initialized at true)

component.html

```
<div>
  <ul class="selection-list">
    <li *ngFor="let item of getSelections()">
      <button class="btn" (click)="deselect(item)" *ngIf="item.selected">
        <i class="fa fa-close"> {{ item.displayName }} </i>
      </button> 
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

---

component.ts

```
    deselect(item: TreeNode<string>): void {
        item.selected = false;
        if((item.children) !== null) {          
            item.children.forEach(element => {
            this.deselect(element);
          });
        }
    }
```